# How to automate LaTeX to PDF conversion with quickrun.vim

Tags: pdf, plugins, latex, vim

I want to automatically convert LaTeX to PDF with `pdflatex`, then open the PDF in Evince using `quickrun.vim`.

I've read the documentation for `quickrun.vim`, and it seems that I should use a function `:function! quickrun#register_outputter(name, outputter)`, but how can I realize that by configuring my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about quickrun.vim, but a simple mapping would also be sufficient. Add this to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd FileType tex noremap <buffer> <F5> :w<CR> :!pdflatex -shell-escape "%" && evince %:p:r.pdf<CR>
```

Hitting  will then run pdflatex and open the pdf in evince.

Comment: thanks , before I get another solution , actually , I am using this way